# Debug a C++ DLL used in ASP MVC application

Tags: c++, asp.net-mvc-5, visual-studio-debugging

I have a C++ DLL in bin folder of my ASP MVC5 web application project. (I have copied and pasted it from the original C++ project as I was unable to add a reference) I am able to call some of the functions of the DLL(used DLLImport). I have a problem in one of the functions. This can only be solved when I will be able to step into the code of the C++ DLL. I also have the code of the C++ project (built using Cmake).
How do I reach the C++ code while debugging from my web application code. If I use F11 I should be able to reach the C++ code.

Comment: Did you debug a net core web project or a net framework project?

Comment: Thanks @PerryQian-MSFT tried to add a reference of dll directly from the debug folder of the  C++ project. I am unable to add it because it is not a .net assembly. When I try to add clr support in the Configuration-> Advanced ->Common runtime Support tab, I am not able to build it. Please tell me if I can add the dll without these configuration changes or not.

Comment: Do you follow my answer to troubleshoot your issue? First, you can try to right-click on your c++ project-->Configuration Properties-->Debugging-->change `Debugger Type` to `Mixed(Net Core or Net Framework)` and then build your project again. Also, when you debug your project in c# project, you should enable `native code debugging`. And I can test it without any errors in my side.

Comment: After enabling the native code debugging in my web project I get and error in my browser which reads: "Could not load file or assembly 'OmpWeb' or one of its dependencies. An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Comment: As you told I used the complete path of the dll in the DllImport, could that have caused problem?

Comment: I think it is not related to the DLLImport path, you should use the full path of the dll in the Debug folder. Due to the error, I  think you should change to set `IIS` to `x64` since you use x64bit native dll. Right-click on your project-->`Properties`--> `Web`-->change `IIS bitness` to `x64`.

Comment: Sure. I think the natcive c++ dll is built with x64. So you should also change IIS to `x64`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Debug a C++ DLL used in ASP MVC application

**1) First**, make sure that make sure that the DLL you are referring to has a **PDB** file or other output file in its folder.

You should open the c++ project in VS IDE and then make sure that you built it with **Debug** and **x64** mode. If so, build it again.

**Then in c# web project**, use **DLLImport** to reference the `xxx.dll` in the output Debug folder which exists pdb and other whole files.

**2) Second**, go to **Tools** --> **Options** --> **Projects and Solutions** --> **Web Projects** --> **Use the 64 bit version of IIS Express**.

**3) Third**, if you debug a net core web project, please right-click on the project--> **Properties**-->**Debug**-->check **Enable native Code Debugging**.

If you debug a net framework web project, please right-click on the project--> **Properties**-->**Web**-->check **Native Code**.

**4) Fourth**, then close VS Instance, delete the **bin** and **obj** folder of the asp.net core project, then restart your web project and test again.

**In addition**, you can check this document [Debug C# and C++ in the same debugging session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code?view=vs-2019).

**Update 1**

Due to the error, I  think you should change to set `IIS` to `x64` since you use `x64` native dll. Right-click on your project-->`Properties`--> `Web`-->change `IIS bitness` to `x64`.

Comment: Thanks @Perry Qian-MSFT I have tried this as well, but the symbols from dll's  (like combase.dll)  keep on loading in Visual Studio and the browser shows " the site can't be reached. localhost refused to connect"

Comment: I think it is related to your project itself or IIS. First, close VS Instance, enter your solution folder and you will find a hidden folder called `.vs` and then enter the folder-->`config`--> and then delete `applicationhost.config` file.And open Visual Studio, right-click on your project-- > `Properties` --> `Web`>and try to change to use another port number.(`https://localhost:xxxx/`)

Comment: I am clueless how much to thank you. It worked and I am able to step into my C++ native code. :)