# Inspect unmanaged C++ objects/variables on Visual studio 2017

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-debugging, unmanaged, code-inspection

So i have one C# desktop application that references a C++ dll. This dll project was developped by other persons, it can't be compiled on visual studio, I use NMake with the parameter -DCMAKE_BUILB=Debug to generate the **.dll & .PDB files**. I copied the files on the C# project reference folder and **enabled Debugging of Unmanaged Code** in the project properties. So im actualy able to debug unmanaged code from the dll. My issue is that i can't inspect any of the object nor the variables im lokking in the unmanaged code side. The **visual studio contextual inspector doen't show** when I passe my mouse on the objects/variables & when trying to add a spy it's not better. **I need to see the values of the objects/variables from the unmanaged code** to make sure it doen't do anything wrong.

Note : a coworker of mine had already opened a thread here [How add spy on Visual studio using unmanaged code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62718730/how-add-spy-on-visual-studio-using-unmanaged-code)
But sadly the thread was closed for lack of details, so I tried to add more details to describe the issue.
Pls don't close this one

Comment: Mixed debugging is on? PDB? check box: required source files to match exactly match the original version - off ?

Comment: Yes mixed debugging is on, pdb are symbol files required for debugging a dll. Where can i find that checkbox ?

Comment: I meant, do you have the PDB's loaded? Also check optimizations is off

Comment: The check box is in tools->options->debugging->general

Comment: ok it's done, how can i make sure that the PDB's are loaded ? For now i just have them in reference folder

Comment: You tried after unchecking the check box? it's still the same?

Comment: You should step into the c++ function so that you can see the c++ variables in it. You can refer to [this document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code?view=vs-2019).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Inspect unmanaged C++ objects/variables on Visual studio 2017

**Suggestion**

**Update 1**

**Please** make sure that you have installed the **C++ development** and **C# development** workload in **VS Installer**. That's all the premises.

**1)** when you reference the path of the dll, make sure that the pdb file already exists under the reference folder(the folder where you referenced the dll) and then [use DLLImport  node](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code?view=vs-2019#create-a-simple-managed-app-to-call-the-dll) to import the c++ functions.

**2)** Tools-->Options-->Debugging-->General-->check the option **Used Managed Compatibility Mode**

**3)** Right-click on your C# project-->**Properties**---> Debugging-->check the option **Enable native code debugging**

**Also**, check `Allow unsafe code` option under **Build**.

**4)** also, if your c++ dll is built with `x64` platform, you should also use `x64` platform to debug your c# main project.

**In addition**, you can refer to [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62210558/debug-a-c-dll-used-in-asp-mvc-application) for more detailed info.

Comment: After trying all of your suggest, i realise that i was missing C++ développement tools on my visual studio. I modified my visual studio instance to add C++ management and now its working fine. Thanks tho :)