# How to use Visual Studio to debug across a C# program calling a C++ dll?

Tags: c#, c++, visual-studio, debugging, visual-studio-2019

I'm writing a C# application in Visual Studio 2019 that calls a C++ dll (to handle some CUDA programming) and I am not able to debug both sections of the code. The debugger works fine in the C# project but is not loading symbols in the C++ project even though they are all running in the same solution and are all set to DEBUG.
To be clear this is not a question about debugging CUDA code)

Any ideas how I might proceed?
I am not sure it is relevant, but here is the test code I am using...

**C#**

```
[DllImport("HoughTest.dll", CallingConvention = CallingConvention.Cdecl)]  
        public static extern float sumArray([MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] float[] x, int n);  

private void button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  
        {  
           // break points placed in this routine do trigger  
            float[] x = new float[] { 0.5f, 1, 2, 3 };  
            float sum = sumArray(x, x.Length);  
            MessageBox.Show("Sum is "+sum);  
        }
```

**C++**

```
extern "C" __declspec(dllexport) float sumArray(float* x, int n)  
    {  
        // break points placed in this routine do not trigger  
        float sum = 0;  
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)  
        {  
            sum += x[i];  
        }  
        return sum;  
    }
```

Comment: You could try running a second instance of visual studio. Set the main project to the C++ dll one. Then use attach to process to have it break on the C++ breakpoints in your editor.

Comment: Are you sure the native symbol path is setup correctly?

Comment: Project > Properties > Debug tab,tick "Enable native code debugging".  You can't step from managed code to native code, so set a breakpoint on the C++ function.  If that breakpoint remains hollow then use Tools > Options > Debugging > General, untick "Just my code".

Comment: Thanks Hans - that did the trick beautifully!

Comment: Well, those options are tradeoff... as it affect breakpoints, tracing, edit & continue and stop on exceptions. As far as I know, it is not possible to have all debugging features for both languages at once.

Comment: Hi Phil - I used the Enable native Code debugging tick box and I am now able to set break points in both the managed C# and unmanaged C++ sections of code. And the debugger stops at both....

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How to use Visual Studio to debug across a C# program calling a C++
> dll?

**Just add an answer for you and thanks to all the community members for their help.**

To debug native C++ code in a managed project, it actually can be done on Visual Studio so far. You can check this official document--[Debug C# and C++ in the same debugging session](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/debugger/how-to-debug-managed-and-native-code?view=vs-2019).

**Suggestion**

**1) First**, before you build your native c++ dll project, you should make sure that the platform is the same as the c# managed project.

For an example, C++ project is `X64` and you should make sure that your managed project also uses `x64`.

**Besides**, right-click on the c++ project-->**Properties**--> **Debugging**-->set **Debugger Type** to `Auto` or `Mixed`.

**2) Second**, when you build your c++ project to generate the dll, you should copy both c++ `dll` and its `pdb` file into the managed project.

**In other words**, when you use dllimport to reference a c++ DLL, you must make sure that both the `dll` and the `pdb` exist in that path.

**3)** When you debug your C# project, you should check the option `enable native code debugging` under managed project **Properties**-->**Debug**.

==========================

If the breakpoint is still not hit, you should try to disable the option **Enable Just My Code** under **Tools**-->**Options**-->**Debugging**-->**General**.

**In addition**, you can also refer to [this similar issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62210558/debug-a-c-dll-used-in-asp-mvc-application/62254606#62254606) for more help.

Comment: Thanks Perry, That is a much better put together answer than I could have managed!